# Old C++ DLLs into C#

Tags: c#, c++, clr, wrapper

I have a C# project that requires me to use an SDK written in C++. I have gotten a little unfamiliar with C++ but I managed to find all the important functions and classes that I will need.

From what I learned, I guess C++/CLR is going to be my best bet.

The SDK itself mostly uses a DLL called "VssSDK.dll" that comes with multiple header files.

It's 2018 so I am hoping that there exists some way of converting that very large DLL into something I can use in my .NET application **without spending 10s of hours creating headers and what not using CLR** (is this what they mean by creating a wrapper?).

I want this thread to be useful for anyone that needs to undertake the same task: Importing old DLLs into a C# project.

Any guideline and information will be helpful.

- SDK compiles on visual studio 2010
- VssSdk.ddl is a shared library
- I need to re-use the classes contained inside of VssSdk.dll
- Needs to be compatible with .NET using 4.6.2 framework
- Hundreds of functions and classes needed from VssSdk.dll
- I have not managed to migrate the SDK demo into VS2017

Comment: If you are worried about spending "10s of hours" converting a large C++ project to .NET, I wouldn't convert it at all. The better bet would be to write a wrapper.

Comment: Hi Ron! Is there a way to automate the process of creating a wrapper?

Comment: Not completely, but there are tools to help, see: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/243d31fb-92c9-4168-97bf-2d10458f8bb2/generating-c-platform-invoke-wrapper-classes-from-a-c-lib?forum=clr

Comment: Links are broken, but can be found on github: https://github.com/kthompson/PInvokeTool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a native method from a native dll, you need to declare it using DllImport attribute and extern keyword. You may see [extern documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern).

To use classes and class methods you should create a wrapper dll first (to transform class methods to functions that takes a first parameter as pointer to an object of the class). You may use the [Wrappit](http://kaldev.wikia.com/wiki/Wrappit) tool.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks this will work. Instead of creating wrappers for the whole SDK, I will make new funcitons in the C++ project that produce what I need and create wrappers for a much smaller number of functions. When using interop this way, the loaded dlls with still work like they would normally right? I.E. If a function I am using in C++ has static variables they be saved/modified when calling the function? This means that if I import a dll, the whole dll is loaded in RAM correct?

Comment: I have a huge problem with this Dll import stuff. I can easilly pass data from C# to C++ and vice versa but as soon as I start calling some "heavier" functions I get **"System.AccessViolationException"** that I can't debug because "HResult=0x80004003" and "<Cannot evaluate the exception source>". My C++ program works fine on it's own but not when I re-use the same functions inside of a "extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)"

Comment: I am very sorry for the delay, I wasn't regularly checking the stackoverflow. I hope the problem is solved by now. If not I think it would be helpful to learn more details on Marshaling: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66245/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-Introducing-Marshaling